# Visualization of span of 3 vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, span

If I visualize 3 vectors in 3d space, is the span of the 3 vectors a 3d region within the 3 vectors? I need help visualizing so I can understand the concept better.

Comment: It's much simpler than that. What's the span of $\{(1,00), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)\}$? It's all of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Any three linear independent vectors span the entire space.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Start of with the three vectors you know and assume they are all different from the zero vector (thus I don't want to span a point).

We start with taking the first vector. He can point in any direction. If the second vectors points in the same direction as the first one, we span a line. Also assume that the third vector also lies in the same direction, then we still span a line. You see, if all those three vectors lie in the same direction, you can only span a line.

If the second vector does not point in the same direction as the first one, we already span a plane.

Now you can take a third vector. If this vector point in the same direction as the plane, you still span the plane. If this vector does not point in the direction of the plane and thus uses your last dimension properly, you span a 3D space.

Comment: Ok so its basically the 3d space within the vectors joined together by 3 planes, correct?

Comment: You span a 3D space if all your vectors use the full 3D space. If your 3 vectors all lie in a plane, you can't get the whole 3D space, and you only span a 2D space. If they all lie on the same line, you can only span a line. What ever you try to do, if they all lie on the same line, you can take as much linear combinations as you want, but they will still keep being on that same line.

Comment: I'm not talking about special cases. I'm talking about vectors that point in completely different directions. Would that some arbitrary triangular prism where any vector within that prism would span the 3 vectors?

Comment: In linear algebra, all vectors start in the origin, and then they point to the direction you said.

Comment: I know that basic concept. I'm just wondering for 3 vectors in R3. Would their span include everything within their corresponding triangular prism region?

Comment: If your prism is not really a real prism anymore and it becomes a triangle, then you span the triangle + the whole plane where the triangle is embedded in. If your prism is still a real prism, you span whole 3D space. If your prism became just a line, then you span that line.

Comment: @btrballin Example: $\alpha_1 (1,0,0) + \alpha_2 (0,-1,0) + \alpha_3 (1,0,1) = (\alpha_1 + \alpha_3, -\alpha_2, \alpha_3)$ covers the whole $\mathbb{R}^3$ if the $\alpha_i$ vary over all of $\mathbb{R}$ each.

Comment: @btrballin In words: the *span* is the space that you **could** reach, when you would make your three vectors arbitrarily long or short; the length of a vector is irrelevant for the span; only the direction matters.

Answer (score 2):

The span $S = <u_1, u_2, u_3>$ consists of all possible linear combinations

$$
\alpha_1 u_1 + \alpha_2 u_2 + \alpha_3 u_3
$$

where the coefficients $\alpha_i$ are arbitrary real numbers, including negative, zero and positive numbers, e.g. +5002, -136 and 0.

The span $S$ will be either a point, a line, a plane in 3D space or the full 3D space, each containing the origin.

This depends on the choice of vectors $u_i$ and how many of them are linear independent.

Note: I assume that your vector space is $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine being in a spaceship in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Start at $\mathbf{0}$. The vectors in question are directions that your ship can travel in (this corresponds to adding that vector on). You can travel any distance, forwards or backwards, along any of these directions (this corresponds to multiplying the vector by a constant $c$ or $-c$).

The span of these vectors is the set of all points your spaceship can get to this way.

It so happens that this set will either be a line, a plane, or the whole space. It will never be, for instance, some cube in $\mathbb{R}^3$. (Why not?)